# Customer Feedback form: I am looking for a solution to a database ERD because it looks inefficient

Tags: database, erd

I am building a dynamic customer feedback form and I have come across a bit of a problem with the structure of the database. I have included an ERD showing what I am trying to do.

The idea is that I wish to try several different feedback forms and see which ones work the best. I can choose specific questions by having a link entity between the FeedbackForm and the Question table. I am not quite sure how the tables should be linking. If you look at the ERD I believe that I should rename "FeedbackType" to "FeedbackTemplate".

The tables are:

- FeedbackType
- FeedbackForm
- Question
- FeedbackFormQuestion (link entity)

[image: ERD of a customer feedback form]

The problem is that the feedback type (which is a type of template) does not "know" the Question table but I think it should. The problem then is that: if I link it the Question table then it will all join together in a circle. I have a feeling this is incorrect! It may be fine doing this - I am not entirely sure on this.

Just for some idea of what the questions are I would have something like:

How easy was it to use the site?

1. Very difficult
2. Not very easy
3. Satisfactory
4. Good
5. Very Easy

It may be a simple problem that I am simply overlooking or just a lack of experience with this type of problem. I am happy with any form of advice but I wish to make sure this is professionally done. It is not that I cannot get something to work - it is more a case of making sure that it is done professionally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a triple relationship between FbType, FbForm and Questions tables.
An example for relationship table between them:

```
    FBFId     FBTId     QId
-----------------------------
      1         1        1
      1         1        2
      1         1        3
```

This way you can link with 3 tables.

You can also add score column to this table and this way getting rid of
the FeedbackFormQuestion table. This way you have 3 table with one relationship table.

Comment: Actually, with what you have said I could actually just keep the FbFQ table and use that as the triple table. I would have to check this out further. Unfortunately I believe there is some kind of conflict going on because I would need the "set" template with the questions AND all of the new FbFQuestions as well. I will get back to you. Thank you for the response anyway.